# Manage Complex Relationships Between Objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand how to model 'complex' relationships between two objects when using object oriented programming.

I can understand how to manage simple relationships, such as when there is a 1:1 or a 1:M mapping between objects, ie;

1:1 Relationship

```
public Car
{
   public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }

   public Engine Engine { get; set; }  // 1:1 relationship here
}

public Engine
{
   public int NumberOfCylinders { get; set; }

   public Car Car { get; set; } // 1:1 relationship here
}
```

1:M Relationship

```
public Father 
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } // 1:M relationship here
}

public Child
{
   public string FullName { get; set; }

   public Father Father { get; set; }  // 1:M relationship here
}
```

.. but the question is, how do I manage the relationship between two objects when the relationship is more complex?

For example, lets assume an example when there is a task that can be completed by either Joe *OR* John (i.e. either person can complete the task). How would I model this?

```
public Task
{
   public string Description { get; set; }

   // what do I put here?
}

public Person
{
   public string FullName { get; set; }

   // what do I put here?
}

var joe = new Person() { FullName = "Joe" };
var john = new Person() { FullName = "John" };
var task = new Task() { Description = "Task that can be completed by either Joe or John" };
```

I am sure that there must be a common pattern that can be used to model situations like these, but I have been unable to find a solution!

Comment: Uh... An M:N mapping? Where either `Task` has a `List<Person> QualifiedPeople` property, and/or `Person` has a `List<Task> AvailableTasks` one. Obviously your code will have to make sure to modify both sides of the relationship so they stay in sync.

Comment: Can a task be completed by `Joe` and `Jon`, or only ever one Person?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
public Task
{
   public string Description { get; set; }

   // what do I put here?
   public Person CompletedByPerson { get; set; }

}

public Person
{
   public string FullName { get; set; }

   // what do I put here?
   public List<Task> CompletedTasks { get; set; }
}
```

It's the same as Father/Child. Only the 'child' is replaced by Tasks.
It will get more complex when multiple persons complete tasks together.